Why is the Linux CPU stalling when having multithreaded memory writes?
HW Specs:

CPU: 64 Cores, 128 Threads, AMD Ryzen Threadripper Pro 5995WX
RAM: 512 GB, Manufacturer unknown, will try to provide if needed

Linux Specs:

OS:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-119-generic

I'm trying to get model training to work with pytorch on a Linux server, where I have observed performance degradation of a factor ~10 after letting a resource intensive training task run for a couple of minutes (Training on 4 GPUs having a multithreaded Dataloader each).
Trying to isolate the root cause for this issue, I have now come up with a minimal test in python reproducing the issue, by continuously writing 1GB of data to RAM. Running this with 32 Threads in parallel (CPU has 128 Threads available) the CPU stalls after <2min, and when directly reducing the number of threads to 16 or 4 threads, the system keeps stalling (htop "PSI some CPU" > 0%) until giving it some cooldown time of approx 1min. I have run the test on another server (48 CPU threads, 160GB RAM) for 10 minutes without any problems (On this server multi-GPU training is also running without any performance degradation).
Opposed to the self-implemented memory write test, I have also tried a benchmark test using sysbench, writing 10TB of data with up to 96 Threads without any problem. This is where I don't really understand the difference, whether this task writes the data only in some sort of buffer without really allocating any RAM memory? I ran the test with the follwing command:
sysbench --threads=96 --time=0 --memory-block-size=128K --memory-total-size=10T --report-interval=1 --memory-oper=write memory run
The main observable difference of sysbench to my python test script was in htop, where sysbench had all threads running as normal priority/user threads (green bars) while my python script caused a large portion being kernel time (red bars), in my understanding caused by a lot of wait time required.
My question now is, does this diagnostic give some indication on why the system is stalling? Might there be a hardware issue with RAM or could this be an issue with the OS? Or what further tests could I do to isolate the root cause?

Edit:
In the following you can find the minimal python script:
import time
import numpy as np
import threading

data = np.zeros((1024, 1024, 1024, 1), dtype=np.uint8)

def allocate_memory():
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        _ = data * 0
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Time: {end_time - start_time:.3f} s")
    
    print(data.shape)

def run_in_threads(num_threads):
    threads = []
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=allocate_memory)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_threads = 32
    run_in_threads(num_threads)


I have now come up with a minimal test in python reproducing the issue, by continuously writing 1GB of data to RAM - could you please share it?

I have added the minimal script I used for the test in the edit.

Do you have swap enabled? Disable it and see if it helps.

As I don't have root privileges, unfortunately I can't simply disable swap memory, that I would need to check with the server admin. But I have ran a test now with docker by setting memory and memory-swap to the same value, which essentially disables swap for my python script process, but I observe still the same behaviour.

Also by observing swap usage in htop, when the cpu stalls, the allocated swap size does not change and is continuous at 2.49G / 8.00G

You didn't say you're using a docker image. Sadly I'm not well versed in how it works. My only recommendation would be to try to update to a newer Ubuntu release e.g. 24.04 LTS but I guess it's not what you can do yourself. I have no clue what's going on.

To clarify, I don't work with docker virtualization in general, but have now set up an image only to disable swap for my test. If you can say with high confidence that swap could be the issue here, I will go a step further and discuss with the admin, but from my standpoint both htop monitoring and the test with the docker container don't indicate interaction with swap. I don't have a clue how to proceed either, that's why I placed my question here. But thank you anyway for looking into this and your input so far.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/52507601/6607497 answer the question?

It seems that the issue is rather related to a hardware problem than to the Linux OS. I have requested some time for maintenance on the server and have tried to locate a potentially faulty RAM module by removing one by one.
In the end there was no specific module identified, but after removing two out of the four my test script did not lead to increasing pressure stall information (PSI some CPU in htop) anymore and ran smoothly. After that I placed the removed RAM modules back in one by one just to check, but the server still runs smoothly ever since. I had now a multi GPU training task with pytorch running overnight with no performance degradation.
I would speculate that one of the RAM modules might not have been inserted correctly, but I can't say for sure.
